# Create hyperlink in class library for MVC action

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to generate a hyperlink in a class library pointing to an MVC action?

We have some custom routes in our application and we generate some notification links in a class library. Currently, we hard code the the path like {domain}/{CustomRoute}/{Controller}/{Action}/{QueryString}. But, I want to to have a better to build these links, like using UrlHelper.

Comment: [UrlHelper.Action()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) is probably what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I just did something like this. Here's how I did it.

First, I wrote methods to creating the URL. The methods take any arguments needed to form the URL. This means the logic for this is in one place, and it can be called from elsewhere in my application.

Then I added some new extension methods to `UrlHelper`. These extension methods in turn call my methods that create the URL. Now, I can just use `@Url.GetMyUrl(args)` from my Razor markup.

Of course, I still have two versions of the URL format that need to sync: One is my methods described above. And the other is in the code that defines the routing maps. But this seems like a reasonable compromise.